# Optimizing Spark JDBC connection read time by adding query parameter

Tags: apache-spark, sql-server-2008, pyspark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

Connecting sql server to spark using the following package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver16. At the moment am reading the entire table however this is bad for performance. To optimize performance I want to pass a query to the following spark.read config. for example select * from my table where record time > timestamp. is this possible? how would I do this?

```
DF = spark.read \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
        .option("dbtable", table_name) \
        .option("user", username) \
        .option("password", password).load()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just filter the data frame that you are creating. Spark supports [predicate pushdown](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-Optimizer-PushDownPredicate.html), which means that the filtering will most likely run on top of the database directly. You can make sure that that works by looking at the SparkUI / Explain Plan